# How to dismiss a popover from parent in swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am new to iOS and swift. I'm trying to show a popover. I have managed to show a popover but the problem is I need to dismiss it from the parent.

I can dismiss the popover from the ViewController itself using this code

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

But I need to do this from the parent view controller.

I have done this so far. On button click
    performSegueWithIdentifier("bookingPopOverSegue", sender: self)

on prepareForSegue,

```
if segue.identifier == "bookingPopOverSegue" {

        var bookingViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! BookingViewController
        var passthroughViews: [AnyObject] = self.timeSlotButtons
        passthroughViews.append(self.scrollView)
        bookingViewController.popoverPresentationController?.passthroughViews = passthroughViews
    }
```

Any idea on how to do this? Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: I have posted what I have done so far

Comment: refer this post it will help you http://gracefullycoded.com/display-a-popover-in-swift/

Comment: See my answer and try it. It should help you...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just call dismiss method using parent's presentedViewController property, like ....

```
self.presentedViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

For Swift 3.0

```
self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score -2):

If your popover *controller* is made public (for instance as a property of your child view controller), then just use it:

```
// 'self' is the parent
// 'popoverController' is the name of the property
self.childViewController.popoverController.dismissPopoverAnimated(<true or false>)
```

In other words, the problem is not the popover, it is its visibility from the parent.

Comment: ViewController does not have a member named "childViewController"

Comment: I know this is an old comment, but still.. You should not make something "just public" for the sake of easy code :)